# Adding a user to BES via Script?

Tags: scripting, automation, bes

I am looking for a way to add users to BES using a script to help automate new user creation process. Is this possible with using any of the resource kits from BlackBerry, or other methods than using the web-based administration? Any help is much appreciated, thanks!